# Angularjs routeProvider templateURL not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ngRoute but I can't seem to get templateURL working. Everything works as expected except when I use templateURL.

I have 4 different files:

test.html

```
<p>{{test}}</p>
```

test.js

```
angular.module("app")
.controller("testController", ["$scope", function($scope) {
    $scope.test = 10;
}])
```

app.js

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.otherwise({"redirectTo": "1"})
        .when("/1", {
            "controller": "testController",
            "template": "{{test}}"
        })
        .when("/2", {
            "controller": "testController",
            "templateURL": "test.html"
        });
});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
        <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:5000/#/1`, it shows 10 as expected. However, when I go to `http://localhost:5000/#/2`, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: I did'n know this trick with `{{test}}`.
Anyway check in the console that you have no errors. like 404 missing file.

Comment: There are no errors in the console. I did notice that going to `http://localhost:5000/#/2` removes `<div ng-view=""></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in `templateURL`,  it should be `templateUrl`